# My equation code doesn't accept \\

Tags: equations

The `\\` in this equation doesn't work . I don't know why. If I use it in `\begin{bmatrix}` it work. I don't know what is now wrong. I have four equation in the group where I want to solve this.

```
\[
x = [1,0]^{T}\quad \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \alpha > 0,\\ 
x = [1,0]^{T}\quad \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \gamma > 0, 
\]
```

[image]

Comment: `\[` is for single line displays, use `amsmath` package for multiline displays, and the `align` environment instead of `\[..\]`

Comment: i use textstudio he dont accept the enviroment \begin{aling}

Comment: is work thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % <--- for advanced math

\begin{document}
With \verb+gather*+ 
\begin{gather*}
x = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \alpha > 0,\\
x = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \gamma > 0,
\end{gather*}
or \verb+gather+ when you like to have numbered equations
\begin{gather}
x = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \alpha > 0,\\
x = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \gamma > 0,
\end{gather}
Similarly with \verb+align*+
\begin{align*}
x & = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \alpha > 0,\\
x & = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \gamma > 0,
\end{align*}
or you may like to have a numbered system of equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x & = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \alpha > 0,\\
x & = [1,0]^{T} \Rightarrow x^{T}Ax = \gamma > 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For more details see [wiki: mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) and/or [wiki: advanced-mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

Comment: @bernard, thank you very much for editing of my answer!

Comment: You're welcome, @Zarko!